# Load child route of route with an empty path into a named outlet

Tags: angular, url-routing

I have a route with an empty path that acts as a guard for all the other components in my application. Its children are components that should be guarded from users who are not authenticated.

One of the routes activates a modal dialog that I would like to load in an auxiliary router-outlet instead of the default outlet.

What would the URL be to load the `home` route into the default router-outlet and the `mydialog` route into the named `popup` router-outlet, given the following route configuration?

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard],
    component: WrapperComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'mydialog',
        outlet: 'popup',
        component: GigSelectionModalComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Things I've tried but didn't work:

- `/#/home(popup:mydialog) -> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'mydialog'`
- `/#/home(popup:/mydialog) -> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'mydialog'`
- `/#/home/(popup:mydialog) -> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'`
- `/#/home/(popup:/mydialog) -> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'`
- `/#/(home//popup:mydialog) -> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'`
- `/#(/home//popup:mydialog) -> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'`

Angular 4.1.3

PS

If I assign a non-empty path `app` to the wrapper route then I can successfully navigate by the following URL: `/#/app/(home//popup:mydialog)`.

However, I insist on using an empty path for the wrapper.

Comment: Not needed - the wrapper route should match all routes that start with the empty string. (except `/login`).

Comment: Never mind, I believe this doesn't work because of a bug. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10726